# Is it possible to use VIEW table on JOIN statement?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

Good Day Folks,

I have a `children_tb` and I JOIN `residents_tbl` to it. Then, on `residents_tbl` I created a **view** named `family_head`.

Is it possible to use `family_head` on another JOIN statement to `children_tbl` query statement?

**Current query**

```
        $query = $this->db->select('*');
        $query = $this->db->from('children_tbl');
        $query = $this->db->join('residents_tbl', 'residents_tbl.residentID=children_tbl.childName', 'full');
        ---> ***I want to add another join here for view (family_head)***
        $query = $this->db->where('childName', $id);
        $query = $this->db->order_by('childID', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('');
```

I try to use

`$query = $this->db->join('family_head', 'family_head.residentID=children_tbl.familyHeadID', 'full');`

but I got an error message:

```
Table 'db_name.family_head' doesn't exist
```

TIA,
C.M.

Comment: You may post an answer if you feel it would help someone, and it's not just a simple typo correction.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was already solved.
table names are just mismatched.